# value of the foreign key as null in spring mvc hibernet using postgresql

Tags: spring, postgresql

I am using spring mvc hibernate with postgresql.I have created two tables employee and accounts in which there is one to many mapping from employee to accounts,and the employee id is passed as the foreign key to accounts table, but i think the id is not generating. In the database table is generated of accounts table with the foriegn key as the employee id which is the primary key of the employee table, but with **null** value.
for table generation

`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Comment: Please provide some code and more details. Is there actually any data in the database? If so how do example rows look like? What is the specific problem you are facing?